# Rails sidekiq pass REXML::Element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sidekiq, rexml

I am attempting to send an `REXML::element` to a worker using sidekiq. However when I do so I get an error: `ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError`

In this case I am taking an XML document that is stored online and running one worker that divides it up into sections and then creates sub workers to process each section.

```
require "rexml/document"
require 'open-uri'
class GroupUploadWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include REXML

  def perform(user_id, ip_address)
    url = URI.parse('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/nick-grn-dev/alldata.xml')
    open(url) do |http|
      @response = http.read
    end
    @doc = Document.new(@response.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1").encode("UTF-8"))
    @doc.root.elements[1].elements.each do |group|
      SingelGroupUploadWorker.perform_async(user_id, ip_address, group)
    end
  end
end
```

The issue I have found is with the passing of the group variable. It works fine if I pass a string but the group variable is a `REXML::Element`. I am afraid I don't understand the system well enough to understand the error. I have done some research online but I don't think I am asking the right questions. Any help would be most appreciated.

Someone suggested that I should add a stack trace to this. The error I was getting was in sidekiq it self so i was not sure how to get till I reproduced the error in the console. This is what occurred in console.

```
1.9.3p286 :011 > SingelGroupUploadWorker.perform_async(1, '127.0.0.1', @doc.root.elements[1].elements[1])
2013-09-26T01:49:32Z 37015 TID-oxoz25ihc INFO: Sidekiq client using redis://localhost:6379/0 with options {:size=>1}
ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::CircularReferenceError: object references itself
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-    3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:75:in `check_for_circular_references'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:252:in `block in encode_json'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:252:in `each'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:252:in `map'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:252:in `encode_json'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:220:in `block in encode_json'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:220:in `map'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:220:in `encode_json'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:48:in `block in encode'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:77:in `check_for_circular_references'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:46:in `encode'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb:31:in `encode'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/to_json.rb:16:in `to_json'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/common.rb:223:in `generate'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/json-1.8.0/lib/json/common.rb:223:in `generate'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq.rb:97:in `dump_json'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:103:in `block (2 levels) in raw_push'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:103:in `map'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:103:in `block in raw_push'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/connection_pool-1.1.0/lib/connection_pool.rb:49:in `with'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq.rb:67:in `redis'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:95:in `raw_push'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/client.rb:44:in `push'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:85:in `client_push'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sidekiq-2.13.1/lib/sidekiq/worker.rb:40:in `perform_async'
from (irb):11
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/suddenlyaware/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that passing any sort of complex objects to the perform method causes similar issues. What I did was try to simplify arguments to either simple strings or numerics.